# Check if directory contain any files except specified

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have multiple commands joined with `&&`. It looks similar to this:

```
(do something1) &&
(for /f "delims=" %f in ('dir /b /a-d ^| findstr /vile "jpg"') do del "%f") &&
(do something2) &&
```

The second line should delete any files except jpg. It works fine when I really have some other files in the directory:

```
C:\Test
    |-- foo.jpg
    |-- bar.jpg
    |-- baz.png
```

But when I haven't any other files, `do something2` will not be started:

```
C:\Test
    |-- foo.jpg
    |-- bar.jpg

Since there are no other files except jpg, `do something2` will not be started.
```

Is there way to fix it, without changing `&&` to `&`?

(As I understand, as a first step it should be checked the existence of non-jpg files. But I haven't found how it could be achieved.)

---

**Edit**

As suggested in comments, here is full code:

```
(if not exist normal mkdir normal) &&
(if not exist small mkdir small) &&
(if exist *.jpg copy *.jpg normal >nul) &&
(for /f "delims=" %f in ('dir /b /a-d ^| findstr /ile "png jpg jpeg gif" ^| findstr /vile "jpg"') do convert "%f" -set filename:f "%t.%e" "normal\%[filename:f].jpg") &&
cd normal &&
mogrify -thumbnail 100x100^> -path ..\small *
```

This code will convert any images (png, gif) to jpg format, using ImageMagick utility and create small preview thumbnails for each of them.

File name collisions, like:

```
cat.png -> cat.jpg
cat.jpg -> cat.jpg
```

are already solved.

Comment: What's wrong with my question? If you downvote, please, leave a short comment.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you appear to be presenting *part* of a command that *seems* to be spread across three lines and *appears* to be entered at the command-prompt. You haven't provided sufficient context, and your requirement "without changing && to &" means "without changing `only if the prior instruction succeeds` to `regardless of the result of the prior instruction`" when this is the logical step. And we don't know what you want to do if there are no non-jpgs. Do *something2* or something else.

Comment: @Magoo Thank you. I posted the full code with a brief explanation.

Comment: And are you executing directly from the prompt or by using a batch file?

Comment: @Magoo Argh... Well, now I discovered that it doesn't work when I paste it into cmd.exe. However, it perfectly works when used inside AutoHotkey script. Probably because AutoHotkey works with `&&` in a bit different way.

Comment: @Magoo Sorry, I fixed a typo in my code and now it works. Obviously new lines should be removed manually. I added them just for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Why not change `&&` to `&` after the FOR loop so that `something2` will be run regardless of `ERRORLEVEL`?

```
(do something1) &&
(for /f "delims=" %f in ('dir /b /a-d ^| findstr /vile "jpg"') do del "%f") &
(do something2) &&
```

**EDIT** I am not sure I fully understand your comment about this being hard. It appears that you want to run `convert` on all .png, .jpeg, and .gif files and not on .jpg files. Is that correct?

Using `||` will execute the next statement only if ERRORLEVEL is not zero (0).

```
if not exist normal (mkdir normal) || GOTO Failure
if not exist small (mkdir small) || GOTO Failure
if exist *.jpg (copy *.jpg normal >nul) || GOTO Failure
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /a-d *.png *.jpeg *.gif') do (
    convert "%f" -set filename:f "%t.%e" "normal\%[filename:f].jpg"
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (GOTO Failure)
)
cd normal || GOTO Failure
mogrify -thumbnail 100x100^> -path ..\small *

:Failure
EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Comment: Mainly, because it will allow errors during execution. But I agree, this is probably the more "sane" way.

Comment: As I understand, trying to implement **"jpg-only vs. jpg-ant-other-files"-check** will be quite hard, yes?